# iOS 7.1 ad-hoc .ipa won't install

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ipa

My enterprise .ipa file (rightly) just hung when I tried to install it on a 7.1 iPad with an older version of XCode. I updated XCode, set my deployment target to 7.1, and now I see the loading bar/clock thing go correctly...and when it's done I am left with a greyed out icon that says "Installing" that I can't click on.  I've tried deleting it and reinstalling, regenerated the .ipa (and recleaning/building my app), and even restarting the iPad.   Everything works fine with older iPads and deploy targets.

What am I missing?

Edit:  I am installing the .ipa file through itunes. (and making sure to update it in itunes so it replaces the old version)

Comment: if you are on Xcode then go to window -> organiser -> under devices tab find your device -> applcations just drag and drop the ipa file there

Comment: Is the IPA signed with a valid (for that device) provisioning profile?

Comment: I'm not our enterprise admin, but from what I understand the profile I have should work with any device. Is that not a real thing?  Can you only install .ipas on devices you'd be able to deploy code to through xcode?

Comment: @Jenny the iPad on which u are testing the ipa must be registered under your provisioning profile.